# AMD radeon not showing up in Ubuntu installation

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon

I have a Lenovo g40 that came with Windows 10. It came with a AMD Radeon R5 M230with 2GB dedicated memory.

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it and it installed with no errors, but I can't see the graphics card anywhere. Here's the output of `lspci|grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

And here's the output of `lshw -C video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

How can I make my system recognize the radeon card?